# What is a word for a person who constantly speaks negatively?

Tags: single-word-requests

Any situation, any time; this person has always something negative to say about it.

It should be a noun or an adjective to describe a person who is a damp cloud walking over every sunshine situations at the cubicle, hoping to drench other people with his miserable comments.

I considered "sourpuss" but would prefer something more important sounding, like "misogynist."

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In British English, "Naysayer" is common for someone who says that something is not possible, won't work, shouldn't be tried, etc.

Answer (score 29):

**killjoy**

> noun
>
> a person who deliberately spoils the enjoyment of others.
>
> "a few killjoys try to reform the seasonal activities"
>
> synonyms:  spoilsport, moaner, complainer, mope, prophet of doom, Cassandra,
>
> Jeremiah, death's head at a feast

Answer (score 18):

Consider this possibility (definition from [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/curmudgeon)):

> **curmudgeon** /kərˈməjən/ *noun* A bad-tempered or surly person.

Answer (score 14):

My favorite of all time comes from a *Saturday Night Live* character: Debbie Downer.  Ever since, when someone's hellbent on constantly reporting about the sucky side of everything, you will often hear someone say to them, "Quit being such a Debbie Downer."

Answer (score 8):

[Negative Nancy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negative_Nancy):

> (pejorative, informal) A person who is considered excessively and
>   disagreeably pessimistic.

A less aggressive synonym, similar to Benjamin's answer.

[Wiktionary]

Comment: Yet equally passively aggressively sexist/genderizing (and, perhaps inadvertently, heterosexist). Yet more antiquated (than "Debbie Downer"), not having a recent pop-culture referent.  Likely best avoided, in any case.

Answer (score 6):

One of my favorite adjectives: **captious**. (Particularly since the flocking of those described onto social media.)

> 1. Marked by a disposition to find and point out trivial faults: *a captious scholar*. [[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=captious)]

or

> marked by an often ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections (*captious critics*) [[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captious)]

Comment: It's a great word, thanks.  The OED gives it a slightly different emphasis - *Apt to catch or take one in; fitted to ensnare or perplex in argument; designed to entrap or entangle by subtlety; fallacious, sophistical*.

Comment: @Dan: It has that meaning (echoed by the second listed definitions on AHD and M-W) when applied to _questions_ or _arguments_. OED definition 2 applies to people, as above: _Apt to catch at faults or take exception to actions; disposed to find fault, cavil, or raise objections; fault-finding, cavilling, carping._ I only included the definition relevant to the OP, but you're right that it has two distinct definitions.

Answer (score 6):

As an additional alternative to the excellent answers already given,
one could say

**wet blanket**

> a person who makes it difficult for other people to enjoy themselves by complaining, by showing no enthusiasm, etc.
>
> one that quenches or dampens enthusiasm or pleasure
>
> [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wet%20blanket)

The mental image I get from this is that of a group of people are enjoying a cheerful campfire, and then someone comes and throws a wet blanket over the fire, putting it out.

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is *buzzkill*.

***buzzkill***  (Urban Dictionary) *when someone or something ruins a special moment which may or may not be drug induced* and (OED) - n. N. Amer. slang *a person who or thing which dampens enthusiasm or enjoyment; a killjoy, a ‘downer’*.

1992   Village Voice (N.Y.) 28 Jan. 51/4   *This February-December romance would allow the old gal to stretch herself past providing the show's weekly racist buzz-kill.*
2003   M. McCafferty Second Helpings 72,   *I will try not to be such a buzzkill. If I succeed, I will write happy journal entries.*

http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buzzkill : one that has a depressing or negative effect

Comment: To a pessimist, optimism is a buzzkill.

Answer (score 2):

**gloomy**

adjective (Oxford English Dictionary)

2. Causing or feeling depression or despondency

> Marvin was such a gloomy robot that even the automated doors sighed at his
>   approach.

or

**dismal**

adjective (Oxford English Dictionary)

1. Causing a mood of gloom or depression

> Here was a dismal soul, dispelling happiness and light wherever his
>   blighted presence was felt.

Comment: He is not just a gloomy person, he is a person who inflicts 'gloom' on other people.

Comment: The definition of gloomy says exactly that: causing (inflicting) depression or despondency.  The word causing implies that the effect is felt by others.

Comment: I wanted to suggest Marvin!

Answer (score 1):

***grinch***

> *US* A person whose lack of enthusiasm or bad temper has a depressing effect on others [C20: from a character in the 1957 children's book How the Grinch stole Christmas by Dr Seuss (1904-91), US writer and illustrator, whose full name was Theodor Seuss Geisel] [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grinch)

***kvetch***

> A chronic, whining complainer [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kvetch)

***crybaby***

> A person who cries or complains readily or often, esp. with little cause.
>   [1850–55, Amer.] [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crybaby)

Answer (score 1):

***killjoy***

1. a person who spoils other people's fun or enjoyment
2. One who spoils the pleasure of others

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/killjoy)

> I don't want to sound like a killjoy, but shouldn't we study tonight?
>
> (*His perpetually negative attitude made him a real killjoy when others were trying to have fun*)